# IOCP, Cross platform libraries?

Tags: c++, iocp

I've recently bumped into something called IOCP on the windows platform, to be more precise: Input/Output Control Ports. This seems to be *the* most efficient way to code your server software when it needs to hold thousands of users concurrently.
(Correct me if I'm wrong, but thread-per-socket, polling, and asynchronous callbacks (thread on every callback) are not efficient enough.)

I am wondering if there are any 3rd party libraries available that implement this concept. I know the win32 api supplies us with CreateIoCompletionPort, FreeBSD has kqueue and linux in general can use /dev/epoll that works somewhat similarly... But isn't there a crossplatform library (such as boost::thread) that handles this stuff for me?

Comment: Actually IOCP stands for I/O completion port not 'control port'.

Comment: And you're definitely NOT wrong about thread-per-client dedication. You quickly run into severe context switching issues, usually within the first thousand clients on most OS's (Windoze is a stellar example of this).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you looked at boost::asio?
I'm not sure if it has all this functionality yet, but I believe that's one of the things it's intended for.

Comment: Now why didn't I think of that :)

Answer (score 2):

I know this is a late reply to this thread, but for those interested in a x-platform library supporting async IO on both Linux/UNIX and Windows, you might want to take a look at [libuv](https://github.com/joyent/libuv).

[libuv](https://github.com/joyent/libuv) was initially constructed as the foundational underpinnings of node.js, but it has evolved to become a powerful abstraction library for many low-level, x-platform concerns including async IO, non-blocking TCP sockets & named pipes, UDP, timers, child process spawning
, high resolution time, thread pool scheduling, etc.

Answer (score 1):

[libevent](http://monkey.org/~provos/libevent/) works on a number of *nix OSes and also runs on Windows.